# How to Change the Text Colour in the Nav Header when the User is on a Page

Tags: css, sass, pug

I made a navigation header and I want the text in the nav header (for example, blog) to turn bright turquoise when the user is on that page.

[My site's nav header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GNBa.png)

In the second photo link below, look at the "Contact Me" section.

[The result I want my nav header to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oD7TD.png)

Here's my code for the menu.json file:

```js
[
    {
        "link": "/",
        "title": "Coder In Pink",
        "label": "Home"
    },
    {
        "link": "/about",
        "title": "About Me",
        "label": "About Me"
    },
    {
        "link": "/blog",
        "title": "Blog",
        "label": "Blog"
    },
    {
        "link": "/contact",
        "title": "Contact",
        "label": "Contact"
    }
]
```

The code for the menu.scss file:

```
.menu__list {
    text-align: center;
}

.menu__item {
    display: inline;
}

.menu__link {
    padding: 0 30px;

    &:active {
        color: #00ffbd;
    }
}
```

The menu.pug file:

```
ul.menu__list
    each menu in data.menu
        li.menu__item
            a.menu__link(
                href=menu.link,
                title=menu.title
            )=menu.label
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery, this could be a simple solution which marks the link that has a matching href value to the current pathname with an "active" class.

```
$(function(){
    var currentPath = location.pathname;
    $('.menu__list .menu__link').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        // if the current path is found in the href make it active
        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(currentPath) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
})
```

Then style the active class.

```
.menu__link.active {
    color: paleturquoise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Aaron! Is there another way to do it without jQuery?

Comment: I'm not familiar with pug but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45700272/10317510) may help you do this with pug.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much, @Aaron! I'll have a look at it.